# why can't "$$" be used as a delimitter in splitting scala string to array?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to split an array in scala, however i cannot seem to split when there is a delimitter like `$$`

Why is this so?

```
var arr = "abc$$def$$hij".split("$$")

println(arr(0)) // prints abc$$def$$hij
```

Comment: It's because the `split` method used regex under the hood and the `$` character is a special character in regex.  If you follow the advice of @ka4eli you should be okay, which essentially tells the regex compiler to treat the `$` as a litteral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = "abc$$def$$hij".split("\\$\\$")
```